# Plus sign "+" on subdomains names

Tags: subdomain

example: hello+all.domain.com works with chrome/firefox. it does not with ie/safari.

I suppose that there isn't a workaround for this, right? thanks

---

I add that using `urlencode` "works": an urencoded url works with both ie/safari, but does not with chrome/firefox. However can't use 2 urls for the same staff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "plus sign" character is not permitted in a valid domain name.  From RFC952:

> A "name" (Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name) is a text string up
>   to 24 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus
>   sign (-), and period (.).  Note that periods are only allowed when
>   they serve to delimit components of "domain style names".

Comment: hmm, I thought you could use underscores too

Answer (score 5):

The definition for host names can be found in [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952) and was updated by [RFC 1152](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) to allow longer host names (24 -> 63).

Even with [IDN (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), the basic limitations regarding the valid characters of RFC 952 still exist, as there are (correction mine):

> 1. A "name" (Net, Host, Gateway, or Domain name) is a text string up
>    to <strike>24</strike> 63 characters drawn from the alphabet (A-Z), digits (0-9), minus
>    sign (-), and period (.).

In IDN, Unicode characters are converted to the allowed set of characters with Punycode, [RFC 3492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492). However, ASCII characters (0 to 127 decimal) are not punified, so the `+` character (43 decimal) will remain as is and thus be invalid.